# How to set TARGET_NO_KERNEL = true when building Android source code

Tags: android, makefile, build, kernel, android-source

Here is the warning message when building `Android 14` source code:

```
build/make/core/Makefile:4889: warning: Neither INSTALLED_KERNEL_TARGET nor INSTALLED_BOOTIMAGE_TARGET is defined when PRODUCT_O
TA_ENFORCE_VINTF_KERNEL_REQUIREMENTS  is true. Information about the updated kernel cannot be built into OTA update package. You
 can fix this by: (1) setting TARGET_NO_KERNEL to false and installing the built kernel to out/target/product/generic_arm64/kern
el, so that kernel information will be extracted from the built kernel; or (2) Add a prebuilt boot image and specify it in BOARD
_PREBUILT_BOOTIMAGE; or (3) extracting kernel configuration and defining BOARD_KERNEL_CONFIG_FILE and BOARD_KERNEL_VERSION manua
lly; or (4) unsetting PRODUCT_OTA_ENFORCE_VINTF_KERNEL_REQUIREMENTS manually.
```

**Here is the source code in: `build/make/core/Makefile`**

```
ifneq ($(strip $(TARGET_NO_KERNEL)),true)
  ifneq ($(strip $(BOARD_KERNEL_BINARIES)),)
    INSTALLED_KERNEL_TARGET := $(foreach k,$(BOARD_KERNEL_BINARIES), \
      $(PRODUCT_OUT)/$(k))
  else
    INSTALLED_KERNEL_TARGET := $(PRODUCT_OUT)/kernel
  endif
else
  INSTALLED_KERNEL_TARGET :=
endif
```

What's the right way to set the `TARGET_NO_KERNEL = true`? And where to set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set `TARGET_NO_KERNEL` to `true`, you can add the following line to your `BoardConfig.mk` file:

```
TARGET_NO_KERNEL := true
```

This will set the `TARGET_NO_KERNEL` flag to `true`. You can also set this flag in your `Android.mk` file by adding the following line:

```
LOCAL_KERNEL := <path-to-your-kernel>
```

You can replace `<path-to-your-kernel>` with the path to your kernel. This will install the built kernel to `out/target/product/generic_arm64/kernel`, so that kernel information will be extracted from the built kernel.